# Extending ViewModelBase class in MVVM Light toolkit

Tags: silverlight, mvvm-light

The MVVM Light toolkit has a ViewModelBase that all ViewModels inherit from. Unfortunately that ViewModelBase is built into the dll for MVVM Light, so I don't know how to extend it.

I want to add the following code to the constructor of the ViewModelBase.

```
if (!App.IsAuthenticated) {
//MVVM Navigation code here 
}
```

I have an IsAuthenticated flag set in my App.xaml.cs that's set to true after a user successfully authenticates with our custom DB/authentication model (running OOB without a membership/role provider).

How do I extend the VMB to include this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get MVVM Light sourcecode from [mvvmlight.codeplex.com](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com) and modify it.

Comment: Sometimes the best solutions are the simplest, or at least, the Noob-iest, because this is one solution that's plain jane. Cheers Daniel.

Answer (score 4):

You can either extend `ViewModelBase` as proposed, or use extension methods. If you are set on avoiding to extend, the extension method model should help you.

Comment: Great! The author has come!

Answer (score 1):

Create a new class that inherits from ViewModelBase

Comment: I thought about that, but every ViewModel by default inherits from ViewModelBase (part of the MVVM Light ViewModel template), so I'd have to remember to manually change the inherits code every time. It's not the end of the world, but I hoped to avoid that.

Comment: You could also change the template (or create a new one) using the Snippets Manager.